# как скопировать эффекты текста в фигме?

Tags: html, css, figma

Хочу скопировать все свойства текста в фигме (раньше можно было так в Avacode сделать). Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать? строго не судите, я -новичок. [image: как скопиро]

Comment: справа сверху есть переключатель - в дев-режим, для разработчика. переключитесь и будете видеть css стили

Comment: спасибо большое!